# What is meant by: int (*b)[100]

Tags: c++, pointers

What is meant  by: `int (*b)[100]`, and what is the clarification of this code to produce this result?

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(int  a[100])
{
    a [1]= 30 ;
    std::cout<<a[1]<< std::endl;
}

void boo(int a[100])
{ 
    std::cout<<a[1]<< std::endl; 
}

int main()
{
    int (*b)[100] = (int (*) [100]) malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
    *b[1] = 20;
    std::cout<< *b[1] << "\t" << b[1] << std::endl;
    foo(*b);
    boo(*b);
    std::cout<< *b[1] << "\t" << b[1] << std::endl;
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
20  0x44ba430
30
30
20  0x44ba430
```

Comment: You can use http://cdecl.org to see what this definition means.

Comment: If you try to learn C++, you might want to skip this and check out `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int foo[100];` declares `foo` as an *array of 100 ints*. The type of `foo` is `int [100]` (just remove foo from its declaration).

`int (*b)[100];` declares `*b` as an *array of 100 ints*. And that implies that `b` is a *pointer* to such array. Thus, you can write *b = &foo;* for example. The type of `b` is `int (*)[100]` (again, just remove b from its declaration).

But just pointing to an array like in the example above is not very interesting because a pointer to the first element of `foo` (i.e. a pointer to int) is sufficient to access `foo`. No need for a pointer to array. Instead, `b` is interesting to dynamically allocate an *array* of `int [100]`. For example:

```
b = (int (*) [100]) malloc(25 * sizeof(int [100])); // allocates an array of 25 int [100]
b[0][99] = 99; // correct
...
b[24][99] = 24099; // correct
b[24][100] = 24100; // incorrect because each b[i] is an array of 100 integers
b[25][0] = 25000; // incorrect because b is an array of 25 elements (an each element is an array)
```

Thus, your program is incorrect because you have allocated an array of *one* `int [100]` only (indeed, `100 * sizeof(int) == sizeof(int [100])`). So you can write those instructions, which are identical:

```
b[0][0] = 0;
*(b[0]) = 0;
*b[0] = 0;
```

But `*b[1]` is incorrect.

Answer (score 13):

- `int (*b)[100]` is an array pointer, a pointer that can point to an array of 100 int.
- `*b[1] = 20;` is a severe operator precedence bug which reads beyond the bounds of the array. It should have been `(*b)[1]`.

Comment: @2501 Indeed. Maybe one day C++ will catch up with C and support VLAs :)

Comment: @Lundin I would like to see VLA's in C++, although I forbid myself from using them on stack, just vla pointers to allocated memory.

Comment: @2501 or you could just program with C++ idioms, and use a vector.

Comment: @StoryTeller I agree.

Comment: Uuh for some reason I thought this was a 2D array, nevermind... rollback.

Comment: `(int (*) [100])` is not superfluous. Without it there is a compile time error.

Comment: It is superfluous in C but not in C++

Comment: Oh right, C++... Sigh, now how did my posts end up under the C++ tag again...  fixed.

Comment: On my argue though, that using malloc in C++ is never correct and therefore it doesn't matter if you cast the result or not, because you shouldn't be using malloc in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

`int (*b)[100]` is a pointer to an int array of 100 elements. The variable `b` points to allocated memory, which is allocated by malloc: `malloc(100 * sizeof(int));`, but this allocates only one row.

The problem is in the next line: `*b[1] = 20;`, this is identical to `b[1][0]`, which is out of bounds of the array. This causes undefined behavior in the program.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between **int (*b)[100];** and **int *b[100];**

```
int (*b)[100]; // A pointer to an array of 100 integers.

int *b[100]; // An array of 100 int pointers.
```

Answer (score 2):

`int (*b)[100]` declares `b` to be a pointer to an array of 100 integers.

The line with `malloc` allocates the memory to which pointer `b` points to. `*b` dereferences the pointer and thus gives us the recently allocated memory. `b[1]` is just an address, it can be rewritten as `b + 1`. That address is 100 integers further from what `b` points to.

`foo` takes a `pointer to int` and assigns the value 30 to the second slot beginning from that pointer (read address). Both `foo` and `boo` just output what resides in that second slot from that pointer.

Try changing the last line to

`std::cout<< *b[1] << "\t" << b[0] << std::endl;`

and see the difference of what address `b[0]` is and what address `b[1]` is, you will find they are separated by 100 integers. On my compiler, i see a difference of 0x190 that is 400 bytes (integer is 4 bytes and 100 integers make 400 bytes).

Comment: *"*b[1] gives us the second slot in the array "*, operator precedence disagrees with you

Comment: If `b[1]` were valid (for instance if you had `int a[2][100]; int (*b)[100] = a;`) it would not be an address, it would be a 100-element array. In this case, `*b[1]` is an invalid dereference. A valid assignment would be `(*b)[1] = 20;`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer understanding weird statements by first typedef'ing them and then trying to relate and see.

For example,

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t; // 8 bit memory
typedef uint8_t b[100]; // create an array b having 100 elements,
                        // where each element occupies 8 bit memory
typedef uint8_t *e;//create a pointer that points to a 8 bit memory

main()
{
 b *c; //create a pointer c pointing to a type b-"array having 100 elements
       // & each element having 8 bit memory". This is equivalent to what 
       // you said - (*b)[100]. Like just moving the *
 b d;//create an array d having 100 elements of 8 bit memory
 e f[100];//create an array of 100 pointers pointing to an 8 bit memory
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564473/pointer-to-a-function-a-different-approach-of-declaring) might also help.